# YouCompleteMe ERROR: Unable to find executable 'npm'. npm is required to install TSServer

Tags: typescript, npm, vim, youcompleteme

When installing YouCompleteMe for vim, I want to install support for Java and Javascript. Following instructions [from here](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#javascript-and-typescript-semantic-completion), I therefore run:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python3.6 ./install.py  --java-completer --ts-completer
```

However, it errors out with the following message:

```
...
[100%] Linking C shared library /home/vagrant/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/cregex/regex_3/_regex.so
[100%] Built target _regex
Downloading jdt.ls from http://download.eclipse.org/jdtls/snapshots/jdt-language-server-0.54.0-202004152304.tar.gz...
Extracting jdt.ls to /home/vagrant/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/eclipse.jdt.ls/target/repository...
Done installing jdt.ls
ERROR: Unable to find executable 'npm'. npm is required to install TSServer.
```

This would be understandable, except I have npm already set up on my `PATH`, as shown by the following:

```
=> npm -v
6.13.4
=> which npm
/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/npm
```

Any guesses on why YouCompleteMe with ts-completer support is failing to install?

Comment: It may not be on the PATH when running as sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any guesses on why YouCompleteMe with ts-completer support is failing to install?

The install fails because you are running install.py as `sudo`, and the location that `nvm` installs node is not in the `secure_path`. The `secure_path` is in use when a script runs as `sudo`.

You can see the different contents of `PATH` and `secure_path` like this:

```
$ echo 'echo $PATH' | sudo sh    # secure_path
$ echo 'echo $PATH' | sh         # your user PATH
```

You can also confirm that `sudo` lacks an `npm` on its path like this:

```
$ which npm
$ sudo which npm
```

What to do?

One option is to run the script without sudo like this:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 ./install.py  --java-completer --ts-completer
```

Another is to copy the nvm bin contents to one of the `secure_path` locations. The `/usr/local/bin` is one of those.

```
$ find $(which npm | xargs dirname) -type l -o -type f | sudo xargs cp -t /usr/local/bin

# test
$ sudo npm -v
$ sudo node -v
```

After doing that, the installer will find `npm`.